# How do I search for the string '--branch' using ack?

Tags: string, search, escaping, ack

In ack you can use the -Q option to escape all the characters in your search string, but that doesn't seem to work if the search string you are using looks like an option for ack.

I am trying to search a group of files for the string '--branch'. So I try this ack command

```
ack -a -Q '--branch'
```

It responds `Unknown option: branch`. It is seeing my search string as an option to be interpreted. Does anyone know what escape characters I can use to use the --branch as a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ack uses the [Getopt::Long module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Mixing-command-line-option-with-other-arguments) to process command line arguments, so it supports the `--` option to indicate that you want option processing to end at that point in the argument list.

```
ack -a -- --branch
```

should therefore work (it does for me).

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for that. I appreciate you taking the time to explain that command line basic as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with --match PATTERN option?

http://betterthangrep.com/